# How to fit (cover) an image inside span tag?

Tags: html, css

I have this code below working perfectly, but I had to use imgcheckbox plugin for the image be selected when clicked (as google photos).

**Example 1 is working the way i want. But when I use the plugin, it inserts a span tag for each image, so css doesnt work as Example 2**

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 2px;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/350/?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/350/125/?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/180/310/?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/300/?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/220/300/?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/225/305/?random">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random">
</div>
```

Example 2:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 2px;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/350/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/350/125/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/180/310/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/300/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/220/300/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/225/305/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the span display `flex` or `inline-flex` with flex grow 1 too:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-grow:1;
}

img {
  flex-grow:1;
  margin: 2px;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/350/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/400/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/350/125/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/180/310/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/250/300/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/220/300/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/225/305/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300/?random"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[@Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete)'s answer is better, but just for reference:

You could "ignore" the `span` by setting `display: contents`. 
This way the image will act as direct child of the div. 
Browser support isn't that good tho according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20contents).

```
div.main > span {
    display: contents;
}
```

---

Demo:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.main > span {
  display: contents;
}

img {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 2px;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/350/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/350/125/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/180/310/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/300/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/220/300/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/225/305/?random"></span>
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to be careful when using this - it removes all contents within those spans from the accessibility tree meaning devices like screen readers will not be able to see it

Comment: @Pete Thank's for the heads up! Wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 0):

fit as "cover" is really meant to be uses with the image as a background image of the block.

you can try switching it to be  something like this.

```
<span style='display:block; background-image:url("https://picsum.photos/200/350/?random");  background-size:cover;   '> </span>
```